# Find function that made HTTP request in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, chrome-debugging

I can see my HTTP requests in the `Network` tab. 
Does Chrome debugger have a way for me to find where in the source code that request was initiated?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code?

Answer (score 1):

There's a column named [Initiator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALmH5.png) there you can check where the request is triggered but if you're re-utilizing a function for all of your requests like most people do, or using a framework or dependency for any XHR request what you see there might be useless, however you can put a conditional breakpoint there and check the call stack. If you're seeing "[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262415/what-is-initiator-other-in-network-in-chrome-console)" in the Initiator column I think you won't be able to get any more answers from the network tab.

My advice is that you put a breakpoint in the function you use for your requests (if you have one) and check the callstack